# (C#) trying to convert a string to a decimal, getting an error about... a DateTime?

Tags: c#, parsing, exception, decimal

I am building a project that involves making operations on numbers stored as characters in a text file.

So I end up as expected with a string containing myumber as an array of characters.

The line that is causing the issue can be summerised as follow:

```
string TolInf = "0.098"

decimal TolInfNum = decimal.Parse(TolInf);
```

And I am getting this error upon execution:
"when converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object".

I do not understand this at all as there is absolutely no date involved in my program, like this type is not even used once.

Thank you in advance for your help that I need greatly.

PS:I am in a somewhat special situation: I can not work on this project on my personnal computer, so I can not share the we project (hence the very limited code).
Shall you need any more precision I will give as much as possible.

I have not tried much to be honest as I do not understand the problem at all

Comment: Your posted code works for me (after adding a `;`). Tip: see [decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse) - although that will not help with the curious DateTime problem

Comment: How it can be? [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZSJvYn)

Comment: You should first try cleaning your project and rebuild it. To make sure what you execute is really what you currently have as source. The code shown shouldn't never produce that error.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the culture:
`decimal TolInfNum = decimal.Parse(TolInf, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Comment: Side note: where in the [mre] guidance on posting code you found the requirement to post your project source? I'm very confused by your "PS:" section. It would be useful if you calrify why you got such impression as the guidance or tour or help pages may need to be updated.

Comment: Back to my workstation, I tried cleaning and rebuilding. I don't seem to have CultureInfo. , Just CultureInfoConverter.  As for the PS section, it just means I can't copy paste the whole code because the machine I am working on is not connected to the internet (safety reasons)

Comment: Final edit: I needed to add System.Globalization to use the cultureInfo class. Now agbinfo solution worked, thank you very much! As of why the system viewed a date here, it will probably remain a mystery